# Redirect url if contains

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I need a htaccess code to redirect this url

> domain.com/download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33.jpeg

to

> domain.com/movies/33.jpeg

IF url contains JPEG 
how it is possible?

Comment: There is no "jpeg" in `domain.com/download.php?server=1&file=/movies/`. What do you mean?

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite from an URL to a script with query string, you can use this simple [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule)

```
RewriteRule ^movies/.*?\.jpeg$ ^download.php?server=1&file=%{REQUEST_URI} [L]
```

When a user enters `http://domain.com/movies/33.jpeg`, the server will serve `/download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33.jpeg`

---

To redirect from URL with query string, you must first capture the parts with [`RewriteCond`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritecond) and then use these parts in a `RewriteRule`

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} file=(.*?\.jpeg)
RewriteRule ^download.php$ /movies/%1? [R,L]
```

When a user enters `http://domain.com/download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33.jpeg`, the server will redirect the browser to `http://domain.com/movies/33.jpeg`

Comment: I want to redirect from download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33.jpeg to http://domain.com/movies/33.jpeg

Comment: You mean the other way round, if user enters `download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33.jpeg` he should be redirected to `movies/33.jpeg`?

Comment: "You mean the other way round, if user enters download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33.jpeg he should be redirected to movies/33.jpeg?" yes

Comment: RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} file=([.*?.jpeg)
RewriteRule ^download.php$ /movies/%1 [R,L]

Doesn't Work. Error 500

Comment: I messed up the regular expression. It should work now.

Comment: Thank you! that works! but i need to replace %20 with space

Comment: There's neither a space nor `%20` in the rules, what do you mean?

Comment: Sorry or my bad English. I tried redirecting site.com/download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33 2.jpeg to site.com/movies/33 2.jpeg but it spaces converted to %20 ( /download.php?server=1&file=/movies/33%202.jpeg ). I want to replace %20 with space